# Laravel Livewire wire:loading wire:target does not work when called from listener

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This is listed as a bug in the discussion section of the repo, but it is now so old that I am sure there must be a better work around.

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/3080

Psuedo code to explain the issue:

#### Component 1 - menu

```php
<button wire:click="$emit('showGallery', 'all')">Show All - Loading Icon does not show/button>
<button wire:click="$emit('showGallery', 'group1')">Show Group 1 - Loading Icon does not show</button>
```

#### Component 2 - gallery

```php
protected $listeners = ['showGallery' => 'getMedia'];

public function getMedia($filter) {
   $this->media = Media::query()->where('filter', $filter)->get()
}
```

```php
<div wire:loading wire:target="getMedia">loading</div>
<button wire:click="getMedia('all')">Show All Media - Loading icon shows</button>
@dump($media)
```

When calling getMedia from within the component, the loading icon shows. When calling it via a listener, it does not.

The gallery is a self-contained component, and I would expect the loading icon to show any time when getMedia is being called, now matter how it is being called.

Comment: Maybe you can add a property to your component, like `public $isLoading = false`, and set it to `true` when `getMedia` is called. Then, in Blade template, you can conditionally show the loading icon based on the value of `$isLoading`

Comment: I did give this a go already, but it seems to have the same behaviour.